# Setting cluster size for k_means from sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm in the process of making clustering for images using *sklearn.cluster.k_means*. The problem is that each cluster consists of 10 almost identical images and I therefore wanna put a set (max?) size for each cluster when calling the sklearn function, but hasn't been able to find any solution to my problem.

Sample input of 8 images:

[image]

The input is an array of image hashes, so for examples if we have 8 pictures, then the array is size (8,16). It currently works for any size, but the output is slightly wrong (like 95% correct), since it sometimes puts a 11th video in one of the clusters (which also means that there are clusters with only 9).

Sample output:

[image]

The output is just an integer of which centroid the image belongs to.

If you have any idea on how to solve this or if there's a better method than k means that might easier support this, I'm all ears.

Edit: Added a sample of the input and output as images.

Comment: Can you put up sample input and expected output for the task ?

Comment: Added sample input and output

Comment: I am still very unclear as to what you are trying to do. But potentially you are saying that you only want the cluster to have X results and then to cluster the rest differently ? I pure MacGyver approach to this would be to pull out the X you want and just rerun the clustering agent.